# Why does a probability function assign each event in the event space a probability? Shouldn’t it assign that probability to outcomes, not events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A probability distribution depicts the expected **outcomes** of possible values for a given data generating process.

An **outcome** is a possible result of an experiment or trial.

All of the possible outcomes of an experiment form the elements of a **sample space**.

This means when we look at a probability distribution (like Gaussian or Cauchy) we are looking at the shape made by the different outcome probabilities in the sample space (assuming our distribution captures the entire sample space).

A formal way to describe a random process (e.g. an experiment) is via a **probability space**.

A **probability space** consists of three elements:

1. a **sample space**;
2. an **event space**, and;
3. a **probability function**.

We already defined the sample space. An **event space** is a set of events, and an **event** is a set of outcomes in the sample space. A **probability function** assigns each event in the event space a probability, which is a number between 0 and 1.

My question concerns that last line. Wouldn’t it make more sense to say that a probability function assigns each **outcome** in the sample space a number between 0 and 1? If we look at a probability distribution, aren’t we looking at many individuals values, each between 0 and 1, which are are the *outcomes* of an experiment (and which all sum to 1)?

Comment: The generic name for what you call "outcomes" is "random variables". They are indeed at the heart of probability, but we deal with them through events : for example, for a certain random variable $X$, "1<X<3" is an event and we need to be able to assign a probability to this event...

Comment: In general, it is not possible to work out the probability of an event by working out the probabilities corresponding to each individual outcome of that event. For example, if you choose a number uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$, then the chance of that number lying in the interval $[0.5,0.6]$ is $0.1$. However, the chance of choosing an individual number in the interval $[0.5,0.6]$ is *zero*. (This is one of the most seemingly paradoxical phenomenons in probability.) So in general, you can't simply "add up" the probabilities of each individual outcome to get the probability of an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a probability distribution on outcomes if we're only interested in the probability distribution on events. Suppose we're flipping coins, and want to model the probability of both coins showing heads (events HH and not-HH). I can flip the coins many times, see that I get 2 heads in 25% of cases, and conclude there is a 25% chance of the event of getting two heads, and a 75% chance of not getting two heads. Note that this requires knowing *nothing at all* about the probability distribution over the full set of outcomes (HH, HT, TH, TT) - it's possible I'm flipping two fair coins, or it's possible that I'm flipping a two-headed coin and a biased coin that only shows heads 25% of the time.

It may not be necessary to define the probability distribution over all outcomes.

Comment: So the probability distribution is the “reality” and corresponds to a distribution of outcome probabilities, but the events, which are subsets of the distribution of outcomes, are the particular restricted range of outcomes we are interested in (defined by our experiment). Would you agree?

Comment: @Cybernetic In a way, outcomes are the set of possible observations, but events group them in ways that we actually care about. If we are defining the probability space of rolling an even number on a die, all we need to do is define that probability as a whole, it is not required that we define the probability of rolling a 2, 4, or 6 individually. The probability space is defined in terms of events rather than outcomes. Outcomes reflect what actually happened, but different observers could group them differently to define different events...

Comment: @Cybernetic like defining the probability space of rolling an odd number, or of rolling a number greater than 4. All use the same sample space and perhaps underlying probabilities on outcomes, but different event definitions and probability functions.